# Python - Tkinter - Paint: How to Paint smoothly and save images with a different names?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, paint, tkinter-canvas

I made a paint program, but I can not draw smoothly and save the images each time with a different names. Please help!

```
from tkinter import *
# by Canvas I can't save image, so i use PIL
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def save():
    filename = 'image.png'
    image1.save(filename)

def paint(event):
    x1, y1 = (event.x), (event.y)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    cv.create_oval((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill='black', width=10)
    #  --- PIL
    draw.line((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill='black', width=10)


root = Tk()

cv = Canvas(root, width=640, height=480, bg='white')
# --- PIL
image1 = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (640, 480), 'white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)
# ---- 
cv.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint)
cv.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

btn_save = Button(text="save", command=save)
btn_save.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: I know, this is awful :(]

Answer (score 6):

You could use continuous drawing instead of drawing separate small circles.
The following example stores the last values of the position of the mouse to draw a line to the current value.

You need to click, and move the mouse to draw; release the click to stop.

The image name includes a number that is incremented by 1 each time you save; you can therefore save all the intermediate images as you draw the full picture.

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def save():
    global image_number
    filename = f'image_{image_number}.png'   # image_number increments by 1 at every save
    image1.save(filename)
    image_number += 1


def activate_paint(e):
    global lastx, lasty
    cv.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint)
    lastx, lasty = e.x, e.y


def paint(e):
    global lastx, lasty
    x, y = e.x, e.y
    cv.create_line((lastx, lasty, x, y), width=1)
    #  --- PIL
    draw.line((lastx, lasty, x, y), fill='black', width=1)
    lastx, lasty = x, y


root = Tk()

lastx, lasty = None, None
image_number = 0

cv = Canvas(root, width=640, height=480, bg='white')
# --- PIL
image1 = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (640, 480), 'white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)

cv.bind('<1>', activate_paint)
cv.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

btn_save = Button(text="save", command=save)
btn_save.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Allegedly not less terrible than yours, but the lines are continuous...

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much!

Comment: Is there a way to add the x-axis on the blank canvas/figure? In my case, I need it for reference, while drawing.

Comment: Yes, you can do that; it is quite straightforward: `cv.create_line(root, 0, 240, 640, 240)`

Comment: I have also modified your code and added a reset canvas option, which clears the canvas, but still leaves all the drawings on the image. So, when I hit the save button it just overlaps all drawings altogether.

Comment: Yes, this feature was not requested by the OP, and was not implemented. It is not difficult to implement; you need to create a new image upon resetting the canvas, so the drawings do not overlap.

Comment: I have opened another query in relation to my own case, can you please have a look at that? Sorry if this is the incorrect way of referring to a question here, but here is the link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66634483/resetting-image-along-canvas-in-tkinter

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **Save As** dialog if you want to save image as other name and extension:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename as saveAs
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def save():
    filename=saveAs(title="Save image as...",filetype=(("PNG images","*.png"),("JPEG images","*.jpg"),("GIF images","*.gif")))
    image1.save(filename)

def activate_paint(e):
    global lastx, lasty
    cv.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint)
    lastx, lasty = e.x, e.y

def paint(e):
    global lastx, lasty
    x, y = e.x, e.y
    cv.create_line((lastx, lasty, x, y), width=1)

    draw.line((lastx, lasty, x, y), fill='black', width=1)
    lastx, lasty = x, y
def clear():
    cv.delete('all')
def exitt():
    exit()

win = Tk()
win.title("Paint - made in Python")
win.iconbitmap('Paint.ico') # Delete this line if you don't have file "Paint.ico" in this folder
lastx, lasty = None, None

cv = Canvas(win, width=640, height=480, bg='white')
image1 = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (640, 480), 'white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)

cv.bind('<1>', activate_paint)
cv.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

save_ = Button(text="Save image", command=save)
save_.pack()

reset=Button(text='Reset canvas',command=clear)
reset.pack(side=LEFT)

_exit=Button(text='Exit',command=exitt)
_exit.pack(side=RIGHT)
win.mainloop()
```

[Paint.pyw - Drawing window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsTRW.gif)